# Rails production assets precompile, but appear blank in the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

The Sass and JS files all get compiled correctly when I `rake assets:precompile` for production, I can see them in the public/assets folder. *However when I try to run the app and view on a web browser it comes up as a 404.* The filenames match the compiled files in the public/assets folder. Everything works fine on Dev, just like all of the other SO questions I came up with.

[image: 404 Error]

This is my original **application.scss**

```
@import 'materialize/components/_color';
@import 'materialize/components/variables';
@import 'materialize';
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons);

.icon-block {
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.icon-block .material-icons {
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

and original **application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require materialize-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

I'm on Windows for development, deploying to a Ubuntu server for production. New to Rails, but I want to do it right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set `config.serve_static_files = true` in config/environments/production.rb and that fixed it. I'll probably have to fiddle with that to get it to work with what will likely be an NGINX server later, but it works locally.

Answer (score 1):

for future googlers - 
nowadays 'serve_static_files' doesnt work. this got changed to:
`config.public_file_server.enabled = true`
for more help see the guide: [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)

Comment: Use url tag to put your url as per SO policy